# Получить ссылки на файлы внутри папки

Tags: парсер, сервер

Всех приветствую! Подскажите, как получить ссылки на файлы внутри папки (локально на Mac) типа "file:///Users/user/images/image.jpeg"? Если это лучше делать не локально, а на сервере, то могу выгрузить на сервер.

Много папок и файлов внутри одной папки, и нужно разом получить ссылки на все эти файлы.

Comment: открываешь терминал, пишешь `find $PWD/PATH_TO_DIRECTORY -follow`

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо! Напишите, как ответ, чтобы я пометил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В UNIX-системах для получения списка файлов есть штатные утилиты, например, открываешь терминал и вводишь

```
find $PWD/PATH_TO_DIRECTORY -follow
```